# Angular close browser

Tags: angular

I would like to store what user does in my angular application.
So i already do this function when user logout or when user is inactive.
But now i would like to do the same action when user close directly the browser or directly the tab.
Currently it's working when user closes directly the tab.
But when user closes directly the browser nothing is happening.
here is my code when i close tab

```
    @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event']) { 
     unloadHandler(event) {
     this.audit = this.setAudit(this.audit);
     this.auditService.add(this.audit).subscribe();
   }
```

Is someone have an idea when i close the browser (all tabs)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `window:beforeunload` instead of the `unload` one:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) { 
     unloadHandler(event) {
     this.audit = this.setAudit(this.audit);
     this.auditService.add(this.audit).subscribe();
   }
```